# How to intregrate python with java Android studio?

Tags: python, android-studio

Let's say I have already done algorithms written in `python`, and now I want to use these algorithms in my **android** code. Can I use `Java` to get output from **python**? I need to send values from `EditText` as a parameter to python to be calculated in the algorithm and get a result. I can use **Android Studio** only with Java. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, Android doesn't support Python natively. You will have to make and host a Python server, and fetch information from there using web APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Make a web `API` using python web framework like **Django**, **Flask**

Then send request to that API endpoint and calculate with your algorithm and return your result.

You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) in Android studio to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Android studio doesn't have native support for python but you could try integrating a web API of python